# where can I find precompiled v8js dll for windows?

Tags: php, javascript, v8

where can I find precompiled v8js dll for windows? I search but i find only the sources!

Comment: Not sure if one can fit all ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are v8 windows builds available at the [project downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/v8cgi/downloads/list)